# Kafka: Group is already rebalancing when enable Sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

I make consumers for kafka with ConsumerFactory in Spring and it works normal and successfully connect to kafka and read messages.

But when I try to add Sleuth to my project, kafka consumers broke and make this log indefinitely:
`Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing`.

The documentation says that sleuth can work out of the box with ConsumerFactory, can you suggest any solution or place where try to find my problem?